# Scrapy Broad Crawl: Quickstart Example Project

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

Would there be any code example showing a minimal structure of a [Broad Crawls](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html#broad-crawls) with Scrapy?

Some desirable requirements:

1. crawl in BFO order; ([DEPTH_PRIORITY](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-priority)?)
2. crawl only from URLs that follow certain patterns; and ([LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/link-extractors.html#link-extractors)?)
3. URLs must have a maximum depth. ([DEPTH_LIMIT](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit))

I am starting with:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor


class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "webspider"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.link_extractor = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow="\.br\/")
        self.collecton_file = open("collection.jsonl", 'w')

    start_urls = [
        "https://www.uol.com.br/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            "url": response.request.url,
            "html_content": response.body
        }
        self.collecton_file.write(f"{data}\n")

        for link in self.link_extractor.extract_links(response):
            yield Request(link.url, callback=self.parse)
```

1. Is that the correct approach to crawl and store the raw HTML on disk?
2. How to stop the spider when it has already collected `n` pages?
3. How to show some stats (`pages/min`, `errors`, number of pages collected so far) instead of the standard log?

Comment: Please post your program code as a text not as image (same for the error message)

Comment: Hi @gangabass, I've updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. It should work, but you are writing to a file manually instead of [using Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) for that.
2. [CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std-setting-CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT). But mind that it will *start stopping* once you reach the specified number of pages, but it will still finish processing some additional pages.
3. I supect you just want to set [LOG_LEVEL](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std-setting-LOG_LEVEL) to something else.